# How to turn off smoothing in R heatmap function?

Tags: r, heatmap

How do you turn off color smoothing in R heatmap function? I've been trying to turn off the smoothing in order to get a white diagonal when plotting a heatmap of correlations in R.

This is what I'm using:

```
(h <- round(cor(data[,c(83,3:39)],use = "pairwise.complete.obs"),2))
heatmap(h,Colv = NA, Rowv = NA)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by smoothing. Maybe you could try setting `scale = "none"` but without a reproducible example I can't really help much.

Comment: @joran It looks like the heatmap is not showing the exact correlation values, as shown by the diagonal not being white. It should be white because the diagonal values are all =1. However, the cells are affected by their neighboring cells and the colors are being smoothed.

Comment: It would help us understand what you mean if you used `dput(data)` to post your data so we could cut and paste it into our sessions.

Comment: I don't think what you're seeing is "smoothing", but it could be "scaling", which is why I suggested what I did. (By default all the values are scaled before plotting.) But again, without reproducible code that we can copy+paste and run ourselves, we're just guessing wildly.

Comment: @nograpes it's a 40x40 correlation matrix so unfortunately i cannot paste it here

Comment: But you _could_ spend some time to construct a smaller example that illustrates your problem, couldn't you?

Comment: @joran Thank you!! Scaling solved it. Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: For future reference, an easy way to simulate a 40 by 40 correlation matrix `h <- matrix(NA, 40, 40); .h <- runif(sum(lower.tri(h))); h[lower.tri(h)] <- h[upper.tri(h)] <- .h; diag(h) <- 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `scale = "none"` to turn off the default scaling of the matrix values.